# What are some good tools for implementing report dashboard for automation?

Tags: automated-testing

I am currently running a bunch of automated tests and recording the results in a SQL database.  Has anyone built a reporting dashboard for automation results before?  What are some good open source tools for doing so?

Comment: You can setup Tesults (https://www.tesults.com) to report build and automated test results including logs, screen captures and files within a few minutes. It is used by teams of all sizes and is free forever so give it try. I am involved with the Tesults team so beware of bias. Tesults does not meet the requirements for your second question about open source but it looks like Extent does. If open source is not a must have and you don't want to maintain any servers Tesults is worth trying. You also get basic bug triage and access to your results anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use fine reporting tool such as Allure framework.  Here is an example of report:
[image]

> Allure is based on standart xUnit results output but adds some supplementary data. Any report is generated in two steps. During test execution (first step) a small library called adapter attached to testing framework saves information about executed tests to XML files. We already provide adapters for popular Java, PHP, Ruby, Python, Scala and C# test frameworks.

Allure is provided by Yandex.

For more details:
http://allure.qatools.ru/

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the [ThoughtWorks radar](http://www.thoughtworks.com/radar/languages-and-frameworks), it suggests you use a open source project called [Dashing.io](http://dashing.io/) .

Also, Jenkins or other CI servers provide some dashboard capabilities such as with https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dashboard+View  and with https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Sectioned+View+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

ATU Graphical Reporter is an Open Source Reporting utility for TestNG. It is basically  a listener for generating customized graphical reports. Following reports can be generated by this listener.

1. Line Charts
2. Bar Charts
3. Pie Charts

Details from the report:

- An Index page -  A Start Page, you can set any Description in this page
- A Consolidated Report Page - Displays all the Runs in the form of Line and Bar Charts
- A Current Run Report Page - For each run, The Current Run page shows the number of Test cases executed in a tabular format along with the Iteration details, a Summary section and a Pie Chart
- A Test Case Report Page - This Page gives the information about a Test Case with detailed steps in a tabular format along with the screenshot, a Summary section, Execution Platform details, Author Details and provides information about Failure / Skipped / Parameters

[image]

My experience: I have used this reporter in a Selenium WebDriver+TestNG project. It is easy to setup and creates a nice visually appealing report for **each run**.

Information taken from: http://automationtestingutilities.blogspot.in/2014/04/ATUReporterForTestNG.html